# Snake Object has no attribute 'rect'?

Tags: python, pygame

I have got a snake object, and have defined self.rect in the draw method. But when I reference snake.rect, it says it has no attribute rect. Anyone know why?
Snake class:

```
class Snake:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 25
        self.height = 25
        self.direction = 1
        self.kill = False
        self.collide = False

    def draw(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, self.rect)

    def events(self):
        # change direction on key press
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if self.keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.direction = 1
        if self.keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.direction = 3
        if self.keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction = 4
        if self.keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction = 2

        if self.rect.colliderect(food.rect):
            self.collide = True
            print(self.collide)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to have called the `draw` method *before* you try to access it.

Comment: Assign the `self.rect` directly in the init.

Comment: @Dschoni, Thanks, but now the snake doesn't move. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Legorooj, O yeah, I am going to put in in the init method, but it doesn't move now. Do you know why?

Comment: You only show a *def* code and not a *calling* code. This makes it hard to help. As mentioned in other comments, the attribute will only be created once you actually called the `draw` method. Trying to reference the attribute before that will raise an error

Comment: Could you show the calling code (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test():
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.text = 'Hello world!'

  def another_function(self, parameter):
    self.variable = parameter
```

Let's look at that simple code. X and Y are initialised as soon as the class is instanciated so:

```
new_instance = Test(4,5)
print(new_instance.text)
```

will work.
However

```
print(new_instance.variable)
```

will not work, as `variable` is not yet bound to the class instance. Once you do:

```
new_instance.another_function(3)
print(new_instance.variable)
```

it will work.